# Service Broker to Send Messages Specific Database bases based on critiera

Tags: service-broker

In Message Broker can you configure to use one queue but based on criteria send to a different Databases or is it a one to one relationship? I am tryibg to figure out if I should use Message broker or SSIS package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Broker conversations are between services, not between queues. You send from a service, to a service. A conversation is tied to exactly a pair of services and cannot change. The same service can participate in any number conversations, with any number of peer services. If you want to send messages to multiple peers, you need to start multiple conversations.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Broker simply acts as a messaging queue for the different Database Mail Profiles you have configured on the server.  If you plan to reuse a mail configuration, then Database Mail is the way to go.  Otherwise, the Send Mail task in SSIS will provide a more customized benefit.